# When does the Google Analytics API zero out ga:adCost? Is there a workaround?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Good afternoon.  The `ga:adCost metric` and the `ga:date` and `ga:referralPath` dimensions are compatible, according to the [reference doc](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html#ga%3amedium).  But when I [query](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) for these three values:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=XXX&dimensions=ga%3Adate%2Cga%3AreferralPath&metrics=ga%3AadCost&filters=ga%3AadCost%3E0&start-date=2011-04-21&end-date=2011-05-05&max-results=50
```

I get no results.  Removing the filter does not change the outcome.  If I remove `ga:referralPath`, I get expected results, with many records with non-zero ad cost.  Other Campaign dimensions are OK, such as `ga:source` and `ga:medium`, though apparently `ga:adContent` is also no good.

At least one other person has seen very similar behavior ([blog here](http://analyticsimpact.com/2010/04/22/adcost-bug-in-google-analytics-api/)).  I've considered that it could be due to sampling and rounding, but it persists for very small date ranges.

Is there a workaround?  `ga:adCost` is not allowed with `ga:transactionId`, which is the only unique identifier of which I'm aware, and even that only applies to customers who make a purchase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is due to there not being a referral path for AdWords visits recorded in Google Analytics. If you want to see where AdWords visits are coming from then you need to use the other campaign dimensions (source, medium, campaign, keyword and adContent).

Comment: That makes sense, in that by definition all AdWords traffic comes from google.com, but it seems strange that they'd be left out entirely, when they could be included with $0.00 values.  Thanks for the quick reply.